# Received an "Ensure Event Failed" error

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
   <Window x:Class="AppTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AppTest" Height="500" Width="1000" Background="Black">
   </Window>
```

Attempted to add Loaded="" with event handler but an error page appeared. I don't know if my XAML code has a mistake. If you have any ideas what/where the error could be, may you explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, forgot to capitalize my namespace from mainwindow.cs

```
   namespace Apptest
```

to

```
   namespace AppTest
```

Very silly mistake.

Comment: Is this the answer?